# Astronomical explanation of twice setting of sun in Jayadratha episode

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, arjuna, kurukshetra, sudarsana

In the  Kurukshetra war, sun appears to set so that Jayadratha comes out of his hiding place; Sun appears again and Arjuna is able to kill Jayadratha before sunset as per his vow. Is there any astronomical explanation for the same?

Comment: The incident describing Krishna hiding the Sun using yoga or Sudarshana Chakra is most likely an interpolation in the Mahabharata. See pg 5-6 of [this excerpt](https://archive.org/download/InterpolationsInTheMahabharata/INTERPOLATIONS%20In%20The%20Mahabharata.pdf) from Annals of BORI. Now if you accept that it's an interpolation, then there is no question of any "astronomical explanation" for the same.